# php check if link has been clicked

Tags: php

Hi I'm a novice at php could some please help. I'm making a website it has a menu, I need it so that if a link like "link1" is clicked page1.php will load into the the mainSection div and if link2 is clicked page2.php will load in mainSection etc. so all the pages: page1, page2, page3 etc will load into this single page depending on what link has been clicked. Is this possible I don't know where to start. Thanks

```
    <body>
        <?php
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" name="link1">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="link2">link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="link3">link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" name="link4">link 4</a></li>    
            </ul>
        ?>

       <div id="mainSection">
            <?php
        if (link1 == true){
             include 'page1.php';
        }
        if (link2 == true){
            include 'page2.php';
        }
        if (link3 == true){
            include 'page3.php';
        }
        if (link4 == true){
            include 'page4.php';
        }
            ?>  
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Why are there PHP tags around the `ul`?

Comment: Why not just use Ajax for this? so much easier

Answer (score 3):

Here's something you can start with

```
<body>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?link=1" name="link1">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="?link=2" name="link2">link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="?link=3" name="link3">link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="?link=4" name="link4">link 4</a></li>    
            </ul>

       <div id="mainSection">
            <?php
        $link=$_GET['link'];
        if ($link == '1'){
             include 'page1.php';
        }
        if ($link == '2'){
            include 'page2.php';
        }
        if ($link == '3'){
            include 'page3.php';
        }
        if ($link == '4'){
            include 'page4.php';
        }
            ?>  
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: @ jidma ohhh im gonna give that a try and see if it works. thanks

Comment: @user244228 don't forget an else for a default, even if there's no link to page '99' some one will try it.

Comment: Hi jidma it just says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php on line 29

Comment: there was a missing closing ")" in `$link == '3'` line

Answer (score 3):

In addition to majid's code you have to check if the link has been set or else it throws an error of undefined $link.

- link 1
- link 2
- link 3
- link 4

```
   <div id="mainSection">
        <?php
    if(isset($_GET['link'])){
    $link=$_GET['link'];
    if ($link == '1'){
         include 'page1.php';
    }
    if ($link == '2'){
        include 'page2.php';
    }
    if ($link == '3'){
        include 'page3.php';
    }
    if ($link == '4'){
        include 'page4.php';
    }
      }  ?>  
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the format of your links to:

```
<a href="/?1" name="link1">link 1</a>...
```

and then change your PHP to:

```
<?php
        if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 1){
             include 'page1.php';
        }
        if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 2){
            include 'page2.php';
        }
        if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 3){
            include 'page3.php';
        }
        if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 4){
            include 'page4.php';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks ummm what do you mean by QUERY_STRING ? sorry I may seem dumb by saying that but I'm really new to php still

Comment: QUERY_STRING is all that comes after the "?" in the URL (ie: 1 in the example given above)